# Android GCM server side messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

So I got the reg_id and can send notifications to my device. However the notifications are all with a default "Push notification message" vs the actual message.
The payload data I am sending is {'message':'this is a test'}.
In iOS APNS I would have done the same but the key being 'alert'.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what is your question ? are you unable to get payload data ? or you want the push notification to be displayed as a notification ?

Comment: Confused on the question as well. Say what you expect to happen, and what did happen, and a little code too.

Comment: Sorry folks. Basically I wanted to know what needed to be done to make server side pushes work. All sorted. The intent for notifications needed to be put into the Android device so when I am sending a payload of data it has to match the intent's keys.